# React componentDidUpdate makes infinit API calls on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with Class Components for the first time, and I'm facing an infinite loop.
My init state is

```
   this.state = {
      selectedYear: null,
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [],
    };
  }
```

I have a function for fetching data

```
  fetchData = () =>
    fetch(
      `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/football_competitions?year=${this.state.selectedYear}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.data,
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: false,
            error,
          });
        }
      );
```

and my componentDidUpdate method

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if (prevState.selectedYear != this.state.selectedYear) {
      this.fetchData();
      console.log(this.state.items);
    }
  }
```

The problem is when I change my year in state, fetchData gets called an infinite number of times.
It's beginner question but I never worked with class components.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per the React documentation, the signature of [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) method is

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot)
```

what you are doing in your code is checking `this.state.selectedYear` with `prevProps.selectedYear` (this will be most probably `undefined`)

Try below,

```
 componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
    if (prevState.selectedYear != this.state.selectedYear) {
      this.fetchData();
      console.log(this.state.items);
    }
  }
```